# Fix F1 network connection issues in Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Windows 8.1 and for some odd reason, I cannot access Excel help page while learning to code in VBA!

For example, after defining a variable for sheets (Dim sh As Worksheet), I would like to see the option available for sh. Delete and although I have my cursor clicked on and flashing on the word 'Delete', it takes me to the Excel home page in Microsoft instead of directly to the source options for the Delete method!

As far as doing my homework goes, while considering the fact that I am pressed for time, I did implement some due diligence, well to the best of my abilities, which by the way is not a lot and here is the best I could find but that still did not seem to resolve the matter at hand: https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/10741/windows-fix-network-connection-issues

In a nutshell, I switched off my MS firewalls and still nothing... When I press F1, the Help window opens however, this message is relayed back to me "Sorry, something went wrong. Please check your network connection and try again."

Problem is, my network connection is functional as I am submitting this question at the very same time that Office seems to be having problems connecting to my already connected internet WiFi session.

[image]

Comment: VBA help in Excel 2016 is supposed to open in a new windows of your default browser, not in the Excel help pane. In the meantime, it is often helpful to press `Shift+F2` while on the interesting keyword.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/1134103/52365. Is your Excel updated?

Comment: Just highlight the keyword and press F1, should load the Microsoft help in your browser